# Non gender oriented way to replace husband/wife

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, kinship-terms, gender-neutral

I’m creating a list of families that lists both partners’ names, ages, wedding date, and divorce date if there is one. To do this I have been using:

```
Husband    Age    Wife    Age    Marriage Date    Divorce Date
```

My cousin got married, and because he is gay *Husband* and *Wife* no longer apply as appropriate titles for the list of families. I’m not sure how to replace *Husband* and *Wife*. I could use *Husband* and *Spouse* but that won’t work where the couple are both female. Using *Partner A* and *Partner B* would seem to negate the “family” aspect of the relationship, considering that you can have a partner and not be married.  Also, *partner* seems very business-like to me — as in *law partners*, *business partners*, etc.

Is there a way to replace husband and wife in a family relationship that still carries the family connotation but is gender neutral? Spouse seems to fit one half the couple, but I’m not sure what then to title the other half.

Comment: Spouse 1 and Spouse 2?

Comment: But if the couple is gay and men, there is no need for gender neutrality = Male spouse and *His* spouse Likewise for the gay female couple = Female spouse and *Her* spouse.

Comment: I think there's something awry in OP's basic preconceptions here. If *spouse* works for "one half the couple", how can it not work for the other half? The only conclusion I can draw is that OP supposes every couple consists of one *dominant* partner, and a lesser "spouse". Interestingly, [according to this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=her+spouse%2Chis+spouse&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), *her spouse* has actually become more common than *his spouse* in recent years.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct term is [***spouse***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spouse):

> The term is *gender neutral*, whereas a male spouse is a husband and a female spouse is a wife.
>   <sub>(My emphasis)</sub>

Both members of the marriage are spouses, regardless of sex.

In the context of your table, `Spouse 1` / `Spouse 2` or `Partner 1` / `Partner 2` (or `A` / `B`) would be perfectly acceptable. Since you've specified `Married Date` in another column, I doubt anyone would be confused about whether or not they were actually married. There's also probably no harm in simply stating `Spouse` twice, like you have for `Age`.

Comment: If they can’t both be `Spouse ¹⁄₂`, make the other one `Spouse ²⁄₂`. That would distinguish them well enough.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking there should be two separate terms but I guess that's not necessarily true. In this situation what would be better *Spouse A and B* or *Spouse 1 and 2*

Comment: Two separate terms like *Spouse* / *Other Spouse*? (just kidding)--FWIW I would prefer `A` / `B` to `1` / `2`, as the latter seems to apply some implicit ranking to the spouses (as though one is more important than the other). `A` / `B` could be read the same way, though it's not as obvious.

Comment: @Justin808 the only way to make separate terms would be for those terms to be gender specific. Since you specifically do not want this, I can see no way of having different terms.

Comment: @tchrist 's suggestion also generalizes to polyamory (1/N, 2/N, ...), which might be useful in the right circumstances.

Comment: Accordingly, you should normalize this to a PERSON table with columns NAME and AGE, a MARRIAGE table with column MARRIAGE, and a MEMBER table with columns NAME, MARRIAGE, MARRY-DATE, and DIVORCE-DATE. That will be much simpler. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I make the assumption that you are tracking mainly from the stance of blood family, the marriage partner and then the additonal information, but I would would use Spouse and Family member:

```
Relative    Age    Spouse     Age    Marriage Date    Divorce Date   
John        36     Jim         34     11.11.11          -------      
Sam         25     Spooner     23     5.12.03           6.12.03
```

Perhaps this gives a level of detail you don't want, but otherwise it negates the gender issue and does not require using *spouse* twice.

Comment: That makes the assumption that OP (or the subject for whom OP is building the table) is related to exactly one of the spouses. That's not a safe assumption in some families—e.g. some Alabamian / royal families. :p